# How to find frames without Name and ID using Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I'm creating some test cases using Selenium WebDriver in C# for a web application. That web application uses different frames for different elements and those frames are not having any Name and ID. After doing some googling I found that frames can be referred with the number too, starting from '0'. So, I used the same; as some of the elements which were throwing error earlier are now working after I used

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);
```

I used it randomly and it worked, but when I use `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);` for referring to the earlier frame it didn't work, for this I have to use `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` for going  back to the last frame.

Questions:

1. Is this the correct method of handling frames without Name and ID?
2. How to provide correct numbering to frames? Lets say there are 7-8 frames then, how I know which frame is at 0, 1 , 2 ...etc
3. Why this reverse method of handling frame is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an frame and then switch to it.

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath(<your frame xpath>));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

For unnamed iFrames I think I would use the SRC attribute, since this should be unique:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(
  driver.findElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'<the contents of the src here')]"))
);
```

I think the frame numbers may change each run depending on the order of loading of the browser. Not sure when it gets its internal ID, I would not depend on it for a page with 7+ iFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source you can use `None` for your frame to go to the parent head frame.

```
driver.switch_to().frame(None)
```